# Extra margin in PWA - can't stretch full height

Tags: swift, xcode, cordova, vue.js, progressive-web-apps

I built a PWA using Vue.js and https://www.pwabuilder.com/.

On IOS (Iphone 11) my app has extra margins on top and bottom that reduce the screen height, as shown on screenshot 1 below. On the Iphone 8 simulator it seems to go full-width. Probably because it is fixed ?

I thought it might be related to my JS code but debugging the app with Safari indicates that the extra margins are more likely linked to the XCode project, as they seem to apply outside my app view.

Has anyone any idea where that might come from ?

I am very unfamiliar with XCode so it might be just that my project has somewhere a max-height set.

Thanks for the help.

screenshot 1:
[image]

screenshot 2: 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone seeing this now and having the same error:

It was an issue of splash screens in Xcode. As some LaunchIcons were missing (typically the one from the test device) if defaulted to another smaller one and launched the app with a smaller height.